# Retrica displays blue pixels instead of the captured image on Android 2.x

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, camera

I installed [Retrica](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.venticake.retrica) on my Samsung Galaxy SL I9003, but when I opened it I could only see blue pixels instead of the image captured by my camera. I tried to change the parameters of the app, reboot my phone and reinstall it, but it's not working anyway.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read on Retrica's website that they're aware of this problem for android 2.x devices and they're working to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a known bug for devices running on Android 2.x. (Samsung Galaxy S1 and its siblings run on Android 2.x.)

From [Retrica's FAQ #14](http://s3.amazonaws.com/bootstlab/html/retrica-faq.html),

> ## I am using an Android device. Why can't I see the preview?
>
> It often occurs if you are using devices that run Android OS 2.x version. Retrica team is aware of the issue and working on a fix. In the meantime, inquire your device manfacturer for any assistance to upgrade your Android OS to the latest version.

Probably, the only way is to unofficially update the Android OS version (to at least Android 4.0 ICS) by flashing custom ROM.